# Will getting the first item from the iterator of a set return a random value?

Tags: java, random, iterator, set

I'm using `Set#iterator().next();` all by itself, and I'm wondering if:

A) Will that cause memory leaks, or at least any kind of avoidable overhead,

and

B) Whether or not item it returns will be a random item, and if I use this method multiple times, it'll give a different item every time?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Iterator<E> iterator()
> ```
>
> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. **The elements are returned in no particular order** (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator()

If you need to get the elements in the same order every time you iterate through the [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), try one of these specific implementations that guarantee order:

- [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html): sorts elements based on their value (natural order)
- [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html): sorts elements based on their value (natural order)
- [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html): sorts elements based on the order they were inserted in the set (insertion order)

The first two implement the [SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs of `Iterator#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29)

> Returns the next element in the iteration.

Which means that it'll return the items in the order they are stored in the `Set`. And regarding the different item, *Yes*, it'll return next(different) item always(till there are more items remaining in the Set) and will terminate(by throwing the [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)) once it has exhausted all of them.